# Reload/refresh application without actually reloading page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

Is is possible to reload/refresh currently active route (and all components currently in the tree) without reloading the whole page/application?

Executing `window.location.reload()` does the job but the problem is that it also does whole page/application reloading wiping out the Redux store.

Comment: I believe dispatching some action that will lead to a change in the Redux store will re-render all the components that is using that changed data from the store

Comment: Are you using `webpack` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

`reload = () => {
      this.props.history.push(your-route-here');
   }`

Execute the function when you want the view to be reloaded.